# Select statement in SQLite recognizing row number

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

I want to write SQLite statement something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

but i don't have such column RowNumber. I have primary key in my table. But is there row number by default that i could use ?

Also i am searching info about writing more complicated SQLite statement. So if you have some links in bookmarks please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is some additional information that helped me. In my case I was interested in an arbitrary set of rowid's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512086/retrieve-sqlite-rows-by-rowid-efficiently/33512116#33512116

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want to use [LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt)

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Which can also be expressed with the following shorthand syntax

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT X,Y
```

Where `X` represents the offset, which is exclusive, and `Y` represents the quantity, so for example

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 50,50
```

Would return rows 51-100

Comment: just out of curiosity. Why do you need OFFSET 0? Isn't SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 enough?

Comment: You are correct, offset is optional if starting from 0. I likely just wrote it out of habit.

Answer (score 4):

The automatically-created rowid for a table can be accessed by a few different names. From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> Every row of every SQLite table has a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "_rowid_" in place of a column name.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ROWID BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Comment: Selecting from rowid from 1 to 10 does not grant you that 10 rows will be returned, it does not guarantee that even 1 row will be returned.

Comment: Rowids are just guaranteed to be unique in sqlite, not guaranteed to be sequential. Only just after a vaccumm command they are sequentially adjusted from one. Most of the time what you proposed would work. But if I do:
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ROWID BETWEEN 1 AND 10;  --returns ten lines
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ROWID BETWEEN 1 AND 10;  
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ROWID BETWEEN 1 AND 10; --returns zero lines, even if there are remaining lines ate the table.  
VACCUUM; --reorders the rowids
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ROWID BETWEEN 1 AND 10;  --returns ten lines again