# How can I select rows by range?

Tags: sql, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select statement in SQLite recognizing row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976925/select-statement-in-sqlite-recognizing-row-number)

For example, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE [row] BETWEEN x AND y`

How can this be done? I've done some reading but haven't found anything specifically correct.

Imagine a list where you want results paged by an X amount of results, so for page 10 you would need results from rows 10 * X to 10 * X + X. Rather than display ALL results in one go

Comment: Don't you mean column? If you change your [row] with [column], you will receive a resultset with all rows that have a value in that particular column between X and Y. Also see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: i guess he wants something like "give me row 20 - 50"

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. Imagine a list where you want results paged by an X amount of results, so for page 10 you would need results from rows 10 * X to 10 * X + X. Rather than display ALL results in one go.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976925/select-statement-in-sqlite-recognizing-row-number

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233091/sqlite-equivalent-for-oracles-rownum

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For mysql you have limit, you can fire query as :

```
SELECT * FROM table limit 100` -- get 1st 100 records
SELECT * FROM table limit 100, 200` -- get 200 records beginning with row 101
```

For Oracle you can use [rownum](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm)

See mysql select syntax and usage for `limit` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

For SQLite, you have `limit, offset`. I haven't used SQLite but I checked it on [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). Check example for SQLite [here](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html).

Comment: This is dangerous. I think the question asks column range and not row count range

Answer (score 12):

Following your **clarification** you're looking for limit:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 5, 5 .
```

Will display 5-9 (5,6,7,8,9)

The syntax follows the pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT [row to start at], [how many to include] .
```

---

The SQL for selecting rows where a **column** is between two values is:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

If you want to go on the row number you can use rownum:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE rownum 
BETWEEN x AND y
```

However we need to know which database engine you are using as rownum is different for most.

Comment: he wants it by range, and not by it´s value, i guess

Comment: this is not true according to MySQL documentation `LIMIT 5, 5` would return **rows 6-10**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use [rownum](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/rownum.html) :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rownum > 10 and rownum <= 20
```

Comment: @paranoid-android wants something for SQLite. You pushed in the right direction, so I found the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233091/sqlite-equivalent-for-oracles-rownum answer which should work for him.

Comment: @PhiLho someone just added the SQLite tag :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `id` is the primary key of table :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
```

For first 20 results

```
SELECT * FROM table order by id limit 20;
```

Comment: id is, but what if records are deleted? There is no guarantee that id from 1 - 20 would give you 20 results.

Comment: @paranoid : I have edited my answer for your query ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using Between condition

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE COLUMN_NAME BETWEEN x AND y ;
```

Or using Just operators,

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE COLUMN_NAME >= x AND COLUMN_NAME   <= y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried your own code?
This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age BETWEEN x AND y
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **LIMIT** clause:

```
/* rows x- y numbers */
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT x,y;
```

refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html